# Difference between 'may have had to stay' and 'may have to stay'?

Tags: vocabulary, word-order

I am confused between

> He may have had to stay late tonight.

and

> He may have to stay late tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "he may have had to stay late tonight", his having to stay late has (possibly) already happened (but we're not sure). If "he may have to stay late tonight", his having to stay late has not happened yet, but is likely.